# Duplicate Value Avoid in sql query

Tags: mysql, sql-server

```
item            qty

1201-10-005-A   1
1110-01-006-A   1
1112-01-006-A   1
1202-01-008-A   1
1202-01-023-A   1
G-1000-00-003-A 1
Q-2252-00-004-D 1
1150-01-002-A   1
1201-01-009-A   1
1201-01-010-A   1
1201-01-012-A   1
1201-01-013-A   1
1201-02-005-A   1
1201-02-006-A   1
1201-04-001-A   1
1201-05-001-A   1
1201-06-002-A   1
1201-06-003-A   1
1201-06-004-A   1
1201-07-001-A   1
1201-07-002-A   1
1201-07-005-A   1
1201-07-006-A   1
1201-07-009-A   1
1201-07-007-A   1
1201-06-004-A   2
1201-07-001-A   2
1201-07-002-A   2
1201-07-005-A   2
1201-07-006-A   2
1201-07-007-A   2
1201-07-009-A   2
1201-10-005-A   2
1202-01-008-A   2
1202-01-023-A   2
1110-01-006-A   2
1201-06-004-A   3
1201-07-001-a   3
1201-07-002-A   3
1201-07-005-A   3
1201-07-006-a   3
1201-07-007-A   3
1201-07-009-A   3
1201-10-005-A   3
1202-01-008-A   3
1202-01-023-A   3
1110-01-006-A   3
1130-03-009-A   3
1201-06-004-A   4
1201-07-001-A   4
1201-07-002-A   4
1201-07-005-A   4
1201-07-006-A   4
1201-07-007-A   4
1201-07-009-A   4
1201-10-005-A   4
1202-01-008-A   4
1202-01-023-A   4
1110-01-006-A   4
1130-03-009-A   4
1110-01-006-A   5
1130-03-009-A   5
1201-01-009-A   1
0004-08-107-A   1
0010-08-012-A   1
1000-00-003-B   1
```

Same item repeat show max quantuty value ony

Comment: The general rule on this site is to try to solve a problem before asking. What did you try ?

Comment: Don't try to use two different RDBMSs at the same time to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Group By:

```
select item,max(quantity) 
from table 
group by item
```

Comment: [Please don't answer bad questions.](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/276637/1679537)

Comment: Sure will follow as stated in the link.